# Logic App running twice with alert monitoring

Tags: azure, automation, azure-logic-apps

I have the following Logic app:
[image: Logic app]

This logic app is triggered when my connection goes above 120, it runs a powershell script which reduces the number of connection. The problem that I am facing is once it runs and the connections go back down from 120 or above the logic app is triggered again because the alert is being triggered, this generally happens minutes from each other. Is there a way I can tweak this logic app to make sure it wont trigger again for maybe 10 minutes after it has been triggered, to stop my powershell script from running twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have persistent value - stored in any of one of cloud services - let me take azure blob for instance.

The immediate running instance can persist the current running time in the Azure Blob storage.

So next instance is triggered - checks for the last run time from the blob - if it is less than 10 minutes. Your logic would be to skip the execution of the PowerShell.

The overall logic will look like below :

[image]

**Note :**
The logic app doesn't have a concept of persistent storage built-in. You can use AzureSQL, CosmosDB,Sharepoint, Azure Storage etc. using their inbuilt connector to achieve this persisting storage functionality.